# JBoss EAP 7.1.0.GA + picketlink 2.7.1.Final causes org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadError

Tags: jboss7.x, picketlink

I'm using an Red Hat JBoss Enterprise Application Platform - Version 7.1.0.GA and trying to use picketlink 2.7.1.Final causes org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadError.

So, I added in standalone.xml

```
<extension module="org.wildfly.extension.picketlink"/>
```

Then ran the picketlink-installer-2.7.1.Final with the ant that gave me: BUILD SUCCESSFUL, and when I try to launch my app with jboss, I get an:

```
WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) Failed to define class org.picketlink.identity.federation.web.handlers.saml2.SAML2IssuerTrustHandler in Module "org.picketlink.federation" from local module loader @58134517 (finder: local module finder @4450d156 (roots: D:\Jboss\bin\..\modules,D:\Jboss\bin\..\modules\system\layers\base)): org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadError: org.jboss.common-core
```

I added the picketlink.xml file with the Handlers:

```
<Handlers xmlns="urn:picketlink:identity-federation:handler:config:2.1"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="urn:picketlink:identity-federation:handler:config:2.1 ">
        <Handler class="org.picketlink.identity.federation.web.handlers.saml2.SAML2IssuerTrustHandler" />
        <Handler class="org.picketlink.identity.federation.web.handlers.saml2.SAML2LogOutHandler"/>
        <Handler class="org.picketlink.identity.federation.web.handlers.saml2.SAML2AuthenticationHandler"/>
        <Handler class="org.picketlink.identity.federation.web.handlers.saml2.RolesGenerationHandler"/>
</Handlers>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added in \Jboss\modules\system\layers\base\org\jboss\common-core\main\jboss-common-4.2.2.GA.jar and an module.xml with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.5" name="org.jboss.common-core">
    <properties>
        <property name="jboss.api" value="private"/>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
    </dependencies>
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="jboss-common-4.2.2.GA.jar"/>
    </resources>
</module>
```

And that error is gone, I have other errors now...